# Ошибка: Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 int main(void) {
  4     char *str;
  5
  6     if( (str = malloc(5 * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
  7         fputs("Ошибка распределения памяти!", stderr);
  8         exit(1);
  9     }
 10
 11     str = "Abby";
 12
 13     puts(str);
 14
 15     free(str); // высвобождаю динамически распределенную память.
 16
 17     return 0;
 18 }
```

Программа компилируется без проблем (gcc в Cygwin). При запуске выдает строку, и аварийно завершается (Aborted (core dumped)). Ошибка возникает в 15 строчке, если убрать 15: то все норм. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема, разумеется, в строке

```
str = "Abby";
```

Что, по-вашему, делает эта строка? Копирует символы в только что выделенную память? Как бы не так: присвоение указателю `str` как в этой строке, так и в строке с `malloc`, просто изменяет значение указателя. В данном случае — на адрес строковой константы `"Abby"`, которую для вас где-то создал компилятор.

Что получается? Получается, что вы пытаетесь освободить память, выделенную компилятором под строковую константу `"Abby"`. Поскольку эта константа не была выделена при помощи `malloc`, понятно, что аллокатор памяти крешится: он этого не ожидал.

А что случилось с выделенной при помощи `malloc` памятью? А ничего: у вас после `str = "Abby"` больше нет указателя на эту память, так что она потеряна. (Это обычно называют «memory leak».)

Что нужно сделать в данной программе? Смотря какого эффекта вы хотите добиться. Если вам просто нужна строка, уберите `malloc` и `free`. Если вам нужно именно выделить память в куче и скопировать символы в выделенную память, используйте `strcpy`. Или откажитесь от `malloc` и используйте `strdup`, если он доступен в вашей runtime-библиотеке.

Что нужно сделать глобально, чтобы подобные ошибки не повторялись? Разобраться в том, как работают строки и указатели в C. Без этого никуда.

Answer (score 3):

Учебники так и не прочитаны... Если нужно перенести данные в выделенную память, то:

```
strcpy( str, "Abby" ); // unsafe!
```

А что происходит тут:

1. Выделяем память, записываем её адрес в `str`.
2. Присваиваем указателю `str` адрес *совершенно другого куска памяти* (в котором лежит строка "Abby")
3. Передаём во `free()` этот адрес (то есть адрес памяти, которые не выделялась `malloc()`) - не удивительно, что `free()` падает
4. Побочный эффект, до которого можно случайно и дожить - выделенная в `malloc()` память так и остаётся неосвобождённой.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в 11 строке. Если не верите - распечатайте адрес, который имеет переменная str. Он будет различный. Отсюда вывод - удаляется не та память, что выделяется.

Comment: @VladD и @KoVadim Точно, в 11: указатель получает адрес строки, точнее адрес первого символа строки, и затирает адрес выделенный malloc(). Спасибо.

Comment: > адрес, который имеет переменная str
@KoVadim ? одно значнее ( без ненужной запутывающей двусмысленности) утверждение : значение которое содержится  в переменной (типа указатель на char) str

как раз таки  адрес str всё время выполнения данного экземпляра main постоянен.

Comment: под словом "имеет" я имел ввиду не сам адрес переменной str,  а адрес, который она хранит - str - это же в данном коде указатель.